# How to configure permissions on application folder to write XML Documents

Tags: windows, visual-studio, permissions

I have a desktop aplication using VS2005.

The application writes an XML document into an application´s folder.

When I run with an administrator account the application runs OK, but when I run as a user without access rights I receive the access denied error message.

My application will be distributed to multiple users, and therefore could not make the release of access by Windows Explorer. Need access to be released when installing my application on the machine User.

How I can solve this problem?

I have to use the folder where the User to installed the application, which is usually C: \ Program Files \ ...

My application will create the following architecture:

```
C:\Program Files\CapProj\Data\ << where the XML files will be located >>
C:\Program Files\CapProj\Imagens\ << images folder >>
```

The .EXE file will be in `C:\Program Files\CapProj\CapProj.EXE`.

My application doesn't use any database system. This application only uses only XML files to store data, because this application will be distributed to many users in Brasil.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your application write files that belong to a user in that user's My Documents folder, not into the application's folder.

You can get the path to the My Documents folder using the .NET Framework with the following C# code:

```
var myDocsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
```

If the XML file is more like application settings, then use Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData or [a more appropriate special folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the user's AppData directory instead. You can use:

```
string appDataDir = Application.UserAppDataPath;
```